# Error: segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: c

I am learning operating system. When I test this code, I have this problem — segmentation fault, core dumped.
How to solve this problem?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    int p,*stat_addr;
    while((p=fork())==-1);
    if(p==0)
        exit(0);
    else
    {
        wait(stat_addr);
        printf("%d\n",*stat_addr);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `stat_addr` is uninitialized.

Comment: You pass an uninitialized pointer to `wait`. Then, you dereference it in the call to `printf`. You should do something like `int stat_addr;`... `wait(&stat_addr); printf("%d", stat_addr);`.

Comment: Besides the undefined behavior from using uninitialized (non-static) local variables, your program is ill-formed because you don't define the `main` function correctly.

Comment: `while((p=fork())==-1);` isn't all that wise. System calls are like elevator buttons - if they don't work, calling them another million times isn't likely to help.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't initialized stat_addr. Do something like:

```
int stat_addr = 10;
```

and then use it like:

```
wait(&stat_addr);
```

Comment: The `_addr` suffix is no longer entirely appropriate (though it works, of course).  The initialization seems pointless.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler i just reused OP's variable and i agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
int status;
int corpse = wait(&status);
```

The corpse is the PID of the dead child (or -1 if there are no children left).  The exit status is encoded in `status` unless `corpse == -1`.

You crash because you have an uninitialized pointer.  I suspect you're confused by the [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) function's prototype:

```
pid_t wait(int *stat_loc);
```

Yes, it takes a pointer, but it must be a pointer initialized to point at something.  Or, more usually, it is the address of an `int` variable, as with `&status` in my suggested usage.